# Acumatica add Virtual field to Data Grid from different table

Tags: acumatica

I would like to add a virtual data field containing a custom db field *UsrSubID* in DB Table **RQRequest**.

I am trying to add the virtual field into a column in data grid on EPApproval screen. Below is my code on attend to use PXDBScalar to get the value for UsrSubID.

The relation between the two DAC is ***RQRequest.noteID = EPApproval.refNoteID***

I get error:

> error: The type name 'usrSubID' does not exist in the type
>   'PX.Objects.RQ.RQRequest' in file: Code#EPOwned(22)

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.TM;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.EP;


namespace PX.Objects.EP{
public class EPApprovalExt: PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.EP.EPApproval>{



      #region UsrCustomField

      [PXString]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName="Sub Account")]
      [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<RQ.RQRequest.usrSubID,Where<RQ.RQRequest.noteID,Equal<Current<EP.EPApproval.refNoteID>>>>))]


      public virtual string UsrCustomField{get;set;}
      public abstract class usrCustomField : IBqlField{}

      #endregion

}

}
```

Comment: The custom field UsrSubID is not part of base DAC RQRequest. Did you add UsrSubID to a cache extension of RQRequest? If no, then create a DAC extension for RQRequest. After that you should refer to the extension instead of the base DAC when you reference your custom field. With standard naming conventions that would be something like RQRequestExt.usrSubID instead of RQRequest.usrSubID

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to add the UsrSubID data field to the RQRequestExt DAC. However I am not able to see any data. I have tried to use standard RQ.RQRequest data fields but I am still not able to see the values in the Data Grid. 

Perhaps my approach is wrong, can you advice with example maybe. 

Atlas the project builds correctly.

Comment: I would advise to manually check values in DB first if you have direct access to run SQL queries on it. You could run a query like update rqrequest set UsrCustomField='test' to make sure there's data available.

Comment: If data is indeed there then it's likely the key relation which is failing: Where<RQ.RQRequest.noteID,Equal<Current<EP.EPApproval.refNoteID>>>>

Comment: I see the problem in your BQL. UsrSubID is exsisted in Database? If not you must use another way to get or return data.

Comment: The UsrSubID field is in DB table. I think the problem is that its not in the DAC RQRequest

Answer (score 0):

I will delete this answer after I help Fillip because I can't comment in his questions.

Fillip if it doesn't exists in DAC you can not get it. So why not declare it in DAC?

If that is default DAC of Acumatica, you can use your package and choose Add Field in your package, or you can create you own.

I think key work `Graph Extension` can help you with this.

> Remeber, your DAC must have UsrSubID Field before you use it to another DAC or Graph. See HB_Acumatica comment